# Backdate / apply a Google analytics filter retroactively

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I've created 2 filters in Google analytics

1. to exclude traffic that comes from my office IP
2. to only include traffic that is on my domain (to prevent cloned sites using my GA tracking code)

Ive just created these and they seem to be working, but these filters only work going forward. How can I backdate the filter so my previous traffic stats follow these filter rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply filters retroactively in Google Analytics.   Filters are applied on incoming data only.   They permanently and irrevocably change the data as it comes in.   You cannot apply a filter retroactively nor can you remove a filter and reset the already filtered data.

The alternative is to use [segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en).   Segments allow you to view a portion of your historical data.  They can be applied retroactively, or they can be removed at any time without destroying data.

Here is a good reference about this with more information on getting started with segments: http://msp-c.com/Stuff-We-Like/March-2015/Do-Google-Analytics-Filters-Apply-Retroactively